# Why can't Unibail-Rodamco-Westfield be purchased in a "plan d'épargne en actions" (PEA)?

Tags: france, pea, siic

I saw this error message in one [plan d'épargne en actions (PEA)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_d%27%C3%A9pargne_en_actions) on  [Fortuneo](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortuneo):

[image]
[image]

This says that  [Unibail-Rodamco-Westfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unibail-Rodamco-Westfield) be purchased in a "plan d'épargne en actions" (PEA). Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.lerevenu.com/eligibilite-pea-dactions-de-siic-unibail-rodamco-westfield ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200306201646/https://www.lerevenu.com/eligibilite-pea-dactions-de-siic-unibail-rodamco-westfield)) explains the reason why Unibail-Rodamco-Westfield cannot be purchased in a “plan d'épargne en actions” (PEA) (summary: because it's a [SIIC](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9_d%27investissement_immobilier_cot%C3%A9e)):

> L'action Unibail Rodamco Westfield n'est pas éligible PEA. En effet, l'[article 8 de la loi de finances pour 2012 (n° 2011-1977 du 28 décembre 2011)](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000025044460&categorieLien=id) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200111200411/https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000025044460&categorieLien=id)) rendait inéligibles les titres des SIIC (Sociétés d'Investissement Immobilier Cotées) et des sociétés foncières européennes comparables au plan d'épargne en actions (PEA) à compter du 21 octobre 2011. Cependant, les actions de ces mêmes sociétés inscrites sur un PEA avant le 21 octobre 2011 peuvent y demeurer après cette date et donc continuer de profiter d'une exonération d'impôt sur les dividendes et les plus-values de cession.

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=fr&tl=en&text=L'action%20Unibail%20Rodamco%20Westfield%20n'est%20pas%20%C3%A9ligible%20PEA.%0A%0AEn%20effet%2C%20l'article%208%20de%20la%20loi%20de%20finances%20pour%202012%20(n%C2%B0%202011-1977%20du%2028%20d%C3%A9cembre%202011)%20rendait%20in%C3%A9ligibles%20les%20titres%20des%20SIIC%20(Soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9s%20d'Investissement%20Immobilier%20Cot%C3%A9es)%20et%20des%20soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9s%20fonci%C3%A8res%20europ%C3%A9ennes%20comparables%20au%20plan%20d'%C3%A9pargne%20en%20actions%20(PEA)%20%C3%A0%20compter%20du%2021%20octobre%202011.%20Cependant%2C%20les%20actions%20de%20ces%20m%C3%AAmes%20soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9s%20inscrites%20sur%20un%20PEA%20avant%20le%2021%20octobre%202011%20peuvent%20y%20demeurer%20apr%C3%A8s%20cette%20date%20et%20donc%20continuer%20de%20profiter%20d'une%20exon%C3%A9ration%20d'imp%C3%B4t%20sur%20les%20dividendes%20et%20les%20plus-values%20de%20cession.):

> The Unibail Rodamco Westfield share is not eligible for PEA. Indeed, article 8 of the finance law for 2012 (n ° 2011-1977 of December 28, 2011) made the titles of SIICs (Listed Real Estate Investment Companies) and European real estate companies comparable to the savings plan ineligible. in shares (PEA) from October 21, 2011. However, the shares of these same companies registered on a PEA before October 21, 2011 may remain there after that date and therefore continue to benefit from a dividend tax exemption and capital gains on disposal.